# MySQL syntax for UPDATE with an IF conditional in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I am trying run a stored procedure but its getting failed due to `IF` condition.I have tried with different ways still no success. can anyone let me know, how to use IF condition in the stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testdb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `change_parent`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `change_parent`(
    IN new_parent BIGINT(20),
    IN folder__id BIGINT(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        directory_path,nav_depth,id
    INTO 
        @dirpath,@depth,@parent
    FROM folders 
    WHERE id = new_parent;
    UPDATE folders


        IF (folder__id != @parent) THEN 
        SET     directory_path = CONCAT(@dirpath,'/',title),
            nav_depth = @depth+1,
            parent__id = @parent
        END IF;
    WHERE id = folder__id;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the error message

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near: `'IF folder__id != @parent THEN SET directory_path = CONCAT(@dirpath,'/',title' at line 13`

Comment: Please copy and paste the **error message**.  Also, is something missing from your text?  Between "getting" and "due" did you mean to insert some words?

Comment: I am having issue with `IF` condition when I remove it works fine but I need to have condition there to update the records. I have to check if `folder___id != @parent` then only I want to perform update otherwise I want to keep it same.

Comment: I may be out of my depth here, but would you want to move that condition to the where-clause? `WHERE id = folder__id AND folder__id != @parent`

Comment: @pbaldauf - I have tried that

Comment: try the below (I just corrected it to remove the error)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (folder__id != @parent) THEN
    UPDATE folders
            SET ...
        WHERE id = folder__id;
END IF;
```